# generate image in javascript inside <li>

Tags: javascript

I try to create a image in javascript, each image have to inside a `<li>` element, 
the name of the image are in a array.

I do this

```
    var imagenes=[];

     var ruta= "images/proyectos/"+datos[0].nombre.replace(/ /g,"_")+"/";

    for(x=1; x<datos[0].imagenes_a_mostrar.length; x++){
        nombreimage=ruta + datos[0].imagenes_a_mostrar[x];

        var laimagen = new Image();
        laimagen.src=nombreimage;
        imagenes= this.$listado.append(laimagen);


    }
```

where

```
   this.$listado=$('<li></li>')
```

is the list

I show in console images ... I only one `<li>` and inside the name like this

```
p.fn.p.init[1]
0: li
accessKey: ""

.....
innerHTML: "<img src="images/proyectos/Mercado_de_las_palmas_renovation/leisurehospitality.jpg"><img src="images/proyectos/Mercado_de_las_palmas_renovation/mixed-used.jpg">"
innerText: ""
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
...
```

How to obtain two `li` one for image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `<li>` variable (`this.$listado=$('<li></li>')`) before, you are adding every image to that one `<li>` only. It is not recreating a `<li>` every time, as you seem to expect.

So, instead of:

```
imagenes= this.$listado.append(laimagen);
```

Use this:

```
imagenes= $('<li>').append(laimagen);
```

That code will append each `<img>` to a separate `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you entire HTML but the code should be like this;

```
var ruta= "images/proyectos/"+datos[0].nombre.replace(/ /g,"_")+"/";
var $ul = $(".ul-to-insert-li");
for(x=1; x<datos[0].imagenes_a_mostrar.length; x++){
    nombreimage=ruta + datos[0].imagenes_a_mostrar[x];

    var laimagen = new Image();
    laimagen.src=nombreimage;
    $ul.append($("<li>").html(laimagen));


}
```

`$("<li>")` parts create jquery li element and changed `.html(laimagen)` just add the image you just created.